# Prove $f: K^3 \rightarrow K^3$ is a symmetry and other things

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the affine function $f:K^3 \rightarrow K^3$ is a symmetry. $$f(x,y,z)=(-1+2x+y+z,1-x-z,2-2x-2y-z)$$Find it’s base and direction and the equations of the associated projection.

---

English is not my first language so I don’t know if I translated that sentence correctly. I have no idea on how to tackle this problem. The only thing I found was that I can express extract the matrix of f and multiply it by itself. I did that and got the identity which means that I proved that f is a symmetry. How do I answer the other questions?

Comment: By "symmetry", I'm guessing you mean "reflection". Is there a particular affine function $f$ that you're looking at?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write the function, just edited my question.

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: Hint: Consider again the matrix for the associated linear operator $g(x, y, z) = f(x, y, z) - f(0, 0, 0)$. What are its eigenspaces? There should be one for eigenvalue $1$ and one for eigenvalue $-1$.

Comment: I got $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = -1$ where $\lambda = 1$ has algebraic multiplicity 2. The eigenspace associated to $\lambda = 1$ is $V_1 = \{ x+y+z=0 \}$ and associated to $\lambda = -1$ $V_{-1} = \{ -x-y = 0, 2y-z=0 \}$. Therefore a basis for $V_1$ would be $\{ (1,-1,0), (0,1,-1)$ and for $V_2$ would be $\{ (-1/2, 1/2, 1) \}$ Am I correct?